# How to fix incorrect channel size in pytorch neural network?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm working with the Google utterance dataset in spectrogram form. Each data point has dimension (160, 101). In my data loader, I used `batch_size=128`. Therefore, each batch has dimension (128, 160, 101).

I use a LeNet model with the following code as the model:

```py
class LeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1   = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2   = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3   = nn.Linear(84, 30)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        out = F.max_pool2d(out, 2)
        out = F.relu(self.conv2(out))
        out = F.max_pool2d(out, 2)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = F.relu(self.fc1(out))
        out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
        out = self.fc3(out)
        return out
```

I tried unsqueezing the data with `dim=3`, but got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_speech.py", line 359, in <module>
    train_loss, reg_loss, train_acc, cost = train(epoch)
  File "train_speech.py", line 258, in train
    outputs = (net(inputs))['out']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 166, in forward
    return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/mixup_erm-master/models/lenet.py", line 15, in forward
    out = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 443, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 440, in _conv_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [6, 1, 5, 5], expected input[128, 160, 101, 1] to have 1 channels, but got 160 channels instead
```

How do I fix this issue?

---

**EDIT: New Error Message Below**

```
torch.Size([128, 160, 101])
torch.Size([128, 1, 160, 101])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:718: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_speech.py", line 363, in <module>
    train_loss, reg_loss, train_acc, cost = train(epoch)
  File "train_speech.py", line 262, in train
    outputs = (net(inputs))['out']
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2
```

I'm unsqueezing the data in each batch. The relevant section of my training code is below. `inputs` is analogous to `x`.

```
print(inputs.shape)
inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1)
print(inputs.shape)
outputs = (net(inputs))['out']
```

---

**Edit 2: New Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_speech.py", line 361, in <module>
    train_loss, reg_loss, train_acc, cost = train(epoch)
  File "train_speech.py", line 270, in train
    loss.backward()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 149, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [128, 400] but expected shape compatible with [128, 13024]
```

---

**Edit 3: Train Loop Below**

```py
def train(epoch):
    print('\nEpoch: %d' % epoch)
    net.train()
    train_loss = 0
    reg_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(trainloader):
        if use_cuda:
            inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()
        inputs, targets_a, targets_b, lam,layer, cost = mixup_data(inputs, targets,
                                                       args.alpha,args.mixupBatch, use_cuda)
        inputs, targets_a, targets_b = map(Variable, (inputs,
                                                      targets_a, targets_b))
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = mixup_criterion(criterion, outputs, targets_a, targets_b, lam)
    
        train_loss += loss.item()
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += (lam * predicted.eq(targets_a.data).cpu().sum().float()
                    + (1 - lam) * predicted.eq(targets_b.data).cpu().sum().float())
    
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    return (train_loss/batch_idx, reg_loss/batch_idx, 100.*correct/total, cost/batch_idx)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the model right there you are using? Could you make sure the first convolutional layer is `nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)`. The error is not reproducible.

Comment: I expanded the error when I used `dim=3`. I'm not sure what happened, but now when I re-executed with `dim=1`, I get a completely different error: `IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2`. 

I am definitely using the right model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand on `axis=1` *a.k.a.* the **channel** axis:

```
>>> x = x.unsqueeze(1)
```

If you're inside the dataset `__getitem__`, then it corresponds to `axis=0`.

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: `IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2`.

Comment: Ok, could you update your question with your current state (with the current error message, and the shape of input `x`)?

Comment: I edited the question below the original part.

Comment: That's because you are trying to access the tensor with the key `'out'`: `outputs` should just be defined as `outputs = net(inputs)`.

Comment: Now I have this error: `RuntimeError: Function AddmmBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [128, 400] but expected shape compatible with [128, 13024]`

Comment: You are not showing the whole code, please be more specific.

Comment: This error occurs after `loss = criterion(...)` and `optimizer.zero_grad()` but before `optimizer.step()`. I don't know what to be more specific about.

Comment: Please go through your question again, by including your training loop. We are missing function `train` and the model definition.

Comment: I included the train function. The model is still the LeNet model I originally included in the question.

Comment: Try removing the  `map(Variable...` line, `Variable` has been deprecated.

Comment: That didn't change anything in the error message.

Comment: Could you print out the shape of `out` right after this line: `out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)`?

Comment: At that point, `out` has shape `torch.Size([128, 13024])`.

Comment: Ok, this is the issue: `self.fc1` **should** have `13024` as `in_features` (*i.e.* its number of neurons). Your `fc1` layer should be defined as `nn.Linear(13024, 120)`.The error was quite misleading indeed.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: There is one last issue. Do you have any idea why the loss would be a `NaN`?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a very different issue. You might want to log those values and find out if it happens in the middle of training or right at the start. If you need any help, I would recommend you create a question with as many details as possible (try not to post the whole code though).